# SUMIF with listdown criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 3 columns naming Team,Side,Score.
Then I created a Listdown which has All,Home, and Away then that will be my criteria in my SUMIF.

so. `=SUMIF(B2:B100,D1)` where D1 is the listdown cell. My goal here is to sum if I choose home or away or either(all). But my Side column only contains Home and Away. What will I do if I want to sum both Home and Away if I pick All in the List? Sorry, I can't explain well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula finalized with ctr+shift+enter, not just enter.

```
'for the count
=SUM(COUNTIF(B:B, IF(D1="all", {"home","away"}, D1)))
'for the sum of scores in column c
=SUM(SUMIFS(C:C, B:B, IF(D1="all", {"home","away"}, D1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Sir. :) this suits my formula well. Thanks. :) glad I ask here.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to sum the score, the formula should look more like this:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B100,D1,C2:C100)
```

For the "All" you can go for "*" like:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B100,IF(D1="All","*",D1),C2:C100)
```

This should do the trick ;)

**EDIT:**
If you just want to count the games then:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B100,IF(D1="All","*",D1))
```

is all you need...

Comment: Thank you, Sir. :) your answer works. :) I forgot about wildcard. however, the first answer works in my needs. Thanks again. :)