# SUMIF with listdown criteria pt.2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I ask earlier about this. here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50868267/8343981) and I used the checked answer.

When I tried to add another listdown with not the same array. I'm having an error if I choose all.

here is my full formula:

`{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((card!$D$2:$D$3938=$D3)*(card!$J$2:$J$3938=(IF($B$4="All",{"H","A"},$B$4)))*(card!$K$2:$K$3938=(IF($B$1="All",{"2016","2017","2018"},$B$1)))*(card!$F$2:$F$3938=(IF($B$3="All",{"YC","Y2C","RC"},$B$3))),MATCH(card!$A$2:$A$3938,card!$A$2:$A$3938,0)),ROW(card!$A$2:$A$3938)-ROW(card!$A$2)+1)>0))}`

`{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(                                      //count unique match.//
IF((card!$D$2:$D$3938=$D3)*                              //if team_col = Team_name.//
(card!$J$2:$J$3938=(IF($B$4="All",{"H","A"},$B$4)))*     //side_col = (All,H,A)//
(card!$K$2:$K$3938=(IF($B$1="All",{"2016","2017","2018"},$B$1)))* //season_col=(all,16,17,18)//
(card!$F$2:$F$3938=(IF($B$3="All",{"YC","Y2C","RC"},$B$3))) //card_col=(All,YC,Y2C,RC)//
,MATCH(card!$A$2:$A$3938,card!$A$2:$A$3938,0)),ROW(card!$A$2:$A$3938)-ROW(card!$A$2)+1)>0))} //rest of count unique match.//`

Whenever I choose All to the three listdown. I get an error. my instinct is that it does not have the same array?. If I use a wildcard it will get and error whatever I choose. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Is this a list using Data Validation (isn't all just blank for these) or a form control (how are you populating the list, is "All" a value in it)?

Comment: The three listdown are B1,B2,B3. yes they are all data validation list. The link above has answer but for only one listdown. when I tried to add two more, I did not get the expexted answer thus it gives me error when I choose "all" on the three listdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `B1`, `B3`, and `B4` to "All", it looks like you're trying to count the number of unique players in the dataset that belong to the team entered in `D3`. Checking against multiple criteria won't work the same here as in a `COUNTIFS` or `SUMIFS`. Try this instead:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((card!$D$2:$D$34=$D3)*IF($B$4="All",1,card!$J$2:$J$34=$B$4)*IF($B$1="All",1,card!$K$2:$K$34=$B$1)*IF($B$3="All",1,card!$F$2:$F$34=$B$3),MATCH(card!$A$2:$A$34,card!$A$2:$A$34,0)),ROW(card!$A$2:$A$34)-ROW(card!$A$2)+1)>0))
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you, Sir!. I learned something new again. :)